# How can I distinguish status cancel internal and cancel external?

Tags: help, status

I have three statuses to display on a table (delivered, cancelled internal and cancelled external) as the title says, how can I distinguish cancel internal and cancel external so the users see the difference in a glance.

Comment: Please add a mockup or wireframe to elaborate the context. What is the difference you are referring to in the question?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that "*Cancelled internal*" is caused by an administrator and "*Cancelled external*" is caused by a user. (I would change the wording - it depends too much on whether you see it from the admin point of view, or the user's.)

If you are a user, and you cancel an order, simply having a red label saying "*Cancelled*" should suffice, as you know what you did.

If an admin cancels an order, I would add a warning / exclamation icon to draw attention to this change in order status, which you as a user did not cause yourself. Preferably with a line about why it was cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you should consider if there is a functional difference between the two different types of cancel.

- Does the user perform a different set of tasks depending on the type of cancel?

If it doesn't change the process or the user's understanding of the process then you would have to consider if it would even be beneficial to display the different cancel types.